# sorting array according to the "sort" of another array

Tags: arrays, numpy, sorting

I have two array r1 and n1. I sort r1 with np.sort(r1) and call the result r2 so that r2 = np.sort(r1). It then must be that r1[i] = r2[j] for some i and j. Can I sort n1 and obtain an n2 such that n[i] = n[j]
In other words, the arrays initially were correlated, but after sorting one of them, they do not correspond to each other anymore, and what I want is to permute n1 in the same way I permuted r1.

I was not able to think of anything

Comment: Your question is very difficult to interpret, but briefly, no for limited interpretations .. consider at least the following problematic cases: arrays of unequal lengths, empty arrays (can't be indexed), arrays with a single value (can `i` and `j` be equal?), arrays which contain all instances of same value (always works?)..

Comment: Have you looked at using `np.argsort`?

Comment: Sorry for having not put my question precisely enough, but I found the answer here : https://www.skytowner.com/explore/sorting_value_of_one_array_according_to_another_in_python